# magento coupon code new rule function not working

Tags: forms, magento, rule, coupon

error image here: http://s17.postimg.org/d1860kfnj/Screenshot_at_2015_12_28_20_22_49.png
So When I go to add a coupon, the navigation bar has unclickable links and I do not get the form for adding a new rule. I've tried everything I can to enable errors but I'm not getting anything. Please help.

Comment: the image you posted is too small.  you can just post the error as text too (preferred)

Answer (score 0):

go to this location  : app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/promo.xml

and check for :

```
<adminhtml_promo_catalog_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setCanLoadExtJs"><flag>1</flag></action>
        <action method="setCanLoadRulesJs"><flag>1</flag></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/promo_catalog_edit_tabs" name="promo_catalog_edit_tabs">
            <block type="adminhtml/promo_catalog_edit_tab_main" name="promo_catalog_edit_tab_main"/>
            <block type="adminhtml/promo_catalog_edit_tab_conditions" name="promo_catalog_edit_tab_conditions"/>
            <block type="adminhtml/promo_catalog_edit_tab_actions" name="promo_catalog_edit_tab_actions"/>
            <action method="addTab"><name>main_section</name><block>promo_catalog_edit_tab_main</block></action>
            <action method="addTab"><name>conditions_section</name><block>promo_catalog_edit_tab_conditions</block></action>
            <action method="addTab"><name>actions_section</name><block>promo_catalog_edit_tab_actions</block></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/promo_catalog_edit" name="promo_catalog_edit"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="js">
        <block type="adminhtml/promo_catalog_edit_js" template="promo/js.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_promo_catalog_edit>
```

is it damaged or not

if not there go to this Block file : adminhtml/promo_catalog_edit

and check it render the layout perfectly

if still not work then let me know i can help you more on this